# Alguém sabe como posso fazer Scroll no Selenium Webdriver em JAVA

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver

Código:

```
WebElement emailsecundario = driver.findElement(By.id("RecoveryEmailAddress"));
emailsecundario.sendKeys(" teste@teste.com.br");        

WebElement gravar = driver.findElement(By.id("submitbutton"));
gravar.click();
```

Alguém sabe como posso fazer Scroll no Selenium Webdriver em Java?

Comment: Explique o que você precisa fazer, acredito que tenha uma solução melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Rolagem **para baixo**:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

Rolagem **Para cima**:

```
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, -250);");
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]